# $window.Firebase is not a constructor Error Message, Firebase Not Loading

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have set up everything "properly". What was working with AngularFire1 version 1 is not working with AngularFire1 version 2. I am receiving an error message that says:

```
$window.Firebase is not a constructor
```

The code:

https://github.com/TimeTravelersHackedMe/AngularFireDemo

The things I have done right:

- Included firebase.js and angularfire.js
- Added 'firebase' to the app included libraries
- Created a firebase config file with the address of my firebase profile
- Created a firebase reference file located at app/scripts/services/firebaseref.js <---- This is where the error is occurring

Here's the code of interest:

app/scripts/app.js:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name angularFireDemoApp
 * @description
 * # angularFireDemoApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('angularFireDemoApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'firebase'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

app/scripts/services/firebaseref.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name angularFireDemoApp.FirebaseRef
 * @description
 * # FirebaseRef
 * Factory in the angularFireDemoApp.
 */
angular.module('angularFireDemoApp')
    .factory('FirebaseRef', function ($window, FirebaseConfig) {
        return new $window.Firebase(FirebaseConfig);
    });
```

app/scripts/services/firebaseconfig.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name angularFireDemoApp.FirebaseConfig
 * @description
 * # FirebaseConfig
 * Constant in the angularFireDemoApp.
 */
angular.module('angularFireDemoApp')
  .constant('FirebaseConfig', 'https://enviedsolutionsangularfire.firebaseio.com');
```